# Regex Filter Query | Google LogPuzzleExercise

Tags: regex, python-3.x

**Note**: I have a query in how regex works for this case. *Even though this is related to a exercise, its not a homework help! since I got the solution file which I am not referring to.*

I am working on this exercise of [log reading](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/exercises/log-puzzle). Its basically reading a Apache log and downloading the image files logged in it.

line 1:

```
10.254.254.28 - - [06/Aug/2007:00:12:20 -0700] "GET /keyser/22300/ HTTP/1.0" 302 528 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686 (x86_64); en-US; rv:1.8.1.4) Gecko/20070515 Firefox/2.0.0.4"
```

line 2:

```
10.254.254.58 - - [06/Aug/2007:00:10:05 -0700] "GET /edu/languages/google-python-class/images/puzzle/a-baaa.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 2309 "-" "googlebot-mscrawl-moma (enterprise; bar-XYZ; foo123@google.com,foo123@google.com,foo123@google.com,foo123@google.com)"
```

So first i just wrote a regex to simple identify all the GETs

---

Get me the string parts

```
pattern = r"GET\s(.+)\b\s"
match_list = re.findall(pattern, log)
if match_list:
    print(match_list[0])
```

This prints

```
/keyser/22300/ HTTP/1.0" 302 528 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686 (x86_64); en-US; rv:1.8.1.4) Gecko/20070515
```

When i tweaked the pattern to `pattern = r"GET\s(.+)\b\sHTTP`  it now prints

```
/edu/languages/google-python-class/images/puzzle/a-baaa.jpg
```

Where in line1 is somehow ignored and i dont know how. Can anyone explain me what regex error am I doing?

Comment: Does it work as you expect if you escape the backslash for the `\b` so that it's `GET\s(.+)\\b\sHTTP`?

Comment: ill try that, but i marked the string as raw r"" so felt its not required

Comment: as mentioned in the Q, with HTTP i get the second line, but why is first line not searched

Comment: since string is raw r"" extra \ are not working

Comment: Ah, you're right, I'm not massively familiar with python, so was just a guess. Looking at the two lines in your file, it's because the last character of the path isn't a word character, which means `/ HTTP` doesn't match `\b\sHTTP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\b` escape character matches word boundaries, which is to say before and after word characters that aren't prefixed / suffixed by another word character. Since the URI segment of the first log line ends with a `/`, which isn't considered a word character it doesn't match the patter `word-break` then `space` then `HTTP`